# Mac App Store Sandboxing - Writing a new file?

Tags: macos, sandbox, appstore-sandbox

I've been playing around with an app I want to submit to the Mac App Store, and part of the functionality is simply grabbing a file the user chose by dragging or opening, and saving a modified of it to the same directory as the original file (but with a different file name).

I don't want to use a 'Save' dialog box, as that destroys the utility of the application I'm building, but it looks like that might be the only way the app would be allowed—under sandboxing requirements—to write a file to an arbitrary location (arbitrary, in this case, being in the same folder as the existing file) on the disk as a new file.

Is there any way I can approach this without disabling sandboxing? Also, if I submit the app without entitlements/sandboxing turned on today, will it be approved by Apple (supposing it passes all the other requirements), or are they already turning down non-sandboxed apps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first question, no, I don't believe there is any way to write to a file the user didn't specify, unless it's either in your app's container, or (as of 10.7.3) in a directory you have a security-scoped URL for. See the documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Security/Conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/AppSandboxInDepth/AppSandboxInDepth.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011183-CH3-SW16). If the user specifies a file, I doubt you get permissions to the enclosing folder, but it's worth a shot.

Answering your second question, as of today, Friday April 27th, 2012, the App Store does not require sandboxing. The latest deadline given was [June 1, 2012](http://thenextweb.com/apple/2012/02/21/apple-is-extending-the-sandboxing-deadline-to-june-1st-for-mac-app-store-developer/).

Comment: Of course, my app was rejected when submitted because it didn't use sandboxing. So, I had to add a Save dialog box (ah well). It seems that only old apps that are being updated can sneak through without sandboxing for now.